# Skip instance in conditional callback block (lambda or Proc)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I noticed that almost all people use Proc.new instead of lambda (I guess because of how it cares/or not about arity) and also it's common to pass the current instance as an argument. However I checked and it works also without |instance| passed as an arg. See the example below

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associated_objects

  before_save :do_something, if: -> { associated_objects.empty? }
end
```

According to official guide and most posts found on the Internet it seems that I should write

```
before_save :do_something, if: Proc.new { |instance| instance.associated_objects.empty? }
```

Is there something wrong with my example using -> and no argument? It's similar to skipping the self as the receiver in `self.some_method` inside model's code and using the implicit receiver.

Comment: yes, I keep using the short version I shown in my first post

Answer (score 6):

You've got it right, the scope of what's evaluated in the Proc or lambda is automatically set to the current instance of the object you're about to save.

From the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) you can see if you wanted to define your own callbacks you have the option to use a Proc or a lambda with the object in scope.

> If a proc, lambda, or block is given, its body is evaluated in the
>   context of the current object. It can also optionally accept the
>   current object as an argument.

I find it interesting that the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-proc) recommend passing in the current instance into the Proc when (as you outlined) it is very common place to leave that info out elsewhere when `self` is implied.